# BJT as switch to let AC through

Tags: transistors, switches, ac, bjt

I am wondering if this is possible, because all the textbook cases I have seen of using the BJT with an AC source involves an AC input and then an amplified AC output... what i would like to do is use it as a switch to either block the AC or let it through. This is because I want to control the AC with 5v logic. Is this possible? I could always use an actual switch to turn on and off the AC but..well isnt the BJT suppose to be able to do the job if  configured properly... or does "BJT as a switch" not REALLY mean a switch.

Ignore the values of the components i paid them no mind i just wanted to graphically represent what i am considering.

The AC is going to be small voltage signal out of a function generator, not mains. 
[image: Example]

Comment: I think if you really want to switch a AC power or high-ish AC voltage you are better off with back-to-back FETs, or a solid-state relay.  (Or possibly a mechanical relay, depending on your requirements.)

Comment: Why don't you use a mechanical relay? You can turn on and off the AC with a cheap 5V relay. And of course you may need to drive the relay with a transistor. Cheap, simple and easy to build.

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible, at least not with a circuit like this.

Transistors can be used to amplify AC signals but only such that the current will never be smaller than zero. That's why in (AC) amplifiers transistors transistors are *biased* with a certain DC current, for example 10 mA.

Then we can vary that 10 mA by for example a 5 mA AC signal. So the actual current through the transistor will actually vary between 5mA and 15 mA.

[Here's an explanation.](http://slideplayer.com/slide/8551786/)

This is called *biasing a transistor*.

You could switch off the biasing and that would stop the transistor from amplifying the signal. That could work for small audio signals for example.

To switch a large AC signal you need a more elaborate circuit. It depends on the properties of the AC signal what kind of circuit you would need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i do understand biasing a transistor, i know about setting the proper bias to not  clip the AC but this all has to do with AC input , i just want to saturate the transistor and have it let the AC through, but i guess i am taking the "as a switch" part to literal. I might just use a real switch in that case.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use a BJT to shunt an AC signal to ground. If the signal is more than a few volts you need a special BJT with a high base-emitter breakdown voltage.

Ideally the transistor is a special symmetrical type (similar forward and reverse beta and breakdown) such as the one shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffxXyl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a common type of circuit found in many consumer audio devices as part of the mute function.